# How can I export a full alignment from IGV as an image?

Tags: sam, ngs, visualization, igv

The [IGV browser](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/) lets you export an alignment as an image (File => Save Image). However, this image only contains those reads that fit in the viewing window:

[image: IGV screenshot]

As you can see in the image above by looking at the scroll bar on the right, this is only a small subset of aligned reads. Is there any way to export an image of the aligned reads that includes *all* reads and not only those currently shown in the window?

Comment: Running an IGV batch script helps increase the number of reads per image, compared with `File | Save image`, but it does **not** solve the issue. To run a script, first make a script file like so with 1 command per line: ```snapshotDirectory ./
goto chr2:28582094-28582790
snapshot chr2_28582094_28582790.png
goto chr4:8203487-8203815
snapshot chr4_8203487_8203815.png``` Run the script using `Tools | Run batch script` menu.

Comment: @TimurShtatland sorry, I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. That looks like a set of scripting commands and I have a vague recollection of having seen something like that for IGV in the past. Could you please post an answer explaining what you are suggesting?

Comment: Oops, pasted the wrong thing. Fixed this. IMO, this is not an answer, but might help partially.

Comment: @TimurShtatland yes, thanks. I'd posted my comment before your edit :). If the scripting approach does give more reads, then it's at least a partial solution and deserves an answer. Could you flesh your comment into an answer? If you'd rather not, I can post one as soon as I've tested it, but you deserve the rep.

Comment: @TimurShtatland well, this is embarrassing. Your comment made me find an old script I had which does exactly this! I had completely forgotten! Please post an answer, you should get the credit, and then I'll just edit it to add what I did to get everything (essentially, you can set `maxPanelHeight` to get more reads).

Comment: Thank you, done. Please feel free to edit. I don't deserve the full credit obviously, so I owe you half. :)

Comment: @TimurShtatland thanks, but that's fine. The credit belongs to Pierre whose post I'd managed to find last time I needed this and then promptly forgot about until your comment reminded me :). And I already have all the editing privileges rep can buy here, so you need it more!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100681/discussion-between-timur-shtatland-and-terdon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running an IGV batch script helps increase the number of reads per image, compared with `File | Save image`, but it does not solve the issue by itself.

To run a script, first make a script file like so with 1 command per line:

```
snapshotDirectory ./
goto chr2:28582094-28582790
maxPanelHeight 10000
snapshot chr2_28582094_28582790.png
```

Run the script using `Tools | Run batch script` menu. The importat trick is the `maxPanelHeight 10000` which is what makes this include more reads than the default snapshot.

You can also convert this into a little shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/igv
sleep 2
echo "snapshotDirectory /tmp/igv"
sleep 2
goto chr2:28582094-28582790
sleep 2
echo "maxPanelHeight 10000"
echo "snapshot chr2_28582094_28582790.png"
```

Then, just open IGV, load the relevant BAM file and run the script like this to connect to IGV via telnet ([credit to Pierre Lindenbaum](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2011/07/controlling-igv-through-port-my.html)):

```
sh foo.sh |  telnet 127.0.0.1 60151
```